# Changing JTable Cell's Font while editing it

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have set the default font in my JTable as show below

```
myTable.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 10));
```

I wanted to show a bigger font in my JTable,while some data is being typed into the cells.So I used **MyTableCellEditor** custom class.

```
public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    JComponent component = new JTextField();

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {

        ((JTextField) component).setText((String) value);
        ((JTextField) component).setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 12));

        return component;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return ((JTextField) component).getText();
    }
}
```

Below is the code where I attached the CustomCellEditor to my table.

```
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new MyTableCellEditor());
```

But this code do not seem to work.The cells font becomes small while editing and once I finish editing and hit enter,the default JTable font which I set ( Verdana 10 ) takes effect.Why is this happening ? I have already set CustomCellEditor font as ( Verdana 12 ) to my cells.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. When I edit a cell the font is bigger and bold. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to get to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: beware: that implementation of cellEditor is **invalid** (because it doesn't notify its listeners)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create a new class for this. Just change the property of the DefaultCellEditor:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 12));
textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(dce);
```