# JTable - How to set text mask for cells in a specific column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, mask

I have a JTable which the user will be able to add, edit, and remove cells (all of this without extra components besides the JTable). I want to set a custom mask (similar to JFormattedTextField) for all the cells in a specific column.

Example:
 The JTable has 2 columns: Time and Description. All the cells from the Time column have HH:MM mask, and the cells from the Description column don't have mask.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems that I found a good solution.
On this thread: [Changing JTable Cell's Font while editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953422/changing-jtable-cells-font-while-editing-it) There's this code on the solving answer:

```
DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(dce);
```

Then I adapted to use a MaskFormatter:

```
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new String[][] { } , new String[] {"Time", "Description"} ) );
JFormattedTextField ftext = new JFormattedTextField();
MaskFormatter mask;
try {
    mask = new MaskFormatter("##:##");
    mask.install(ftext);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(ftext));
```

This was basically what I was looking for. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I've been trying to achieve the same thing, but when I tried your implementation, only the first cell I click on in the column is affected by the mask. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015273/how-can-you-validate-the-first-column-of-a-jtable-with-regex) about validating JTable fields for an ip address.  In the accepted answer the SO User (peeskillet) shows how to validate input for the JTable with a regex as the 'mask'.  If you can adapt the regex to your mask and study his code he kindly contributed it should get you going in the right direction.

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

The code I am referring to:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class TableVerifyInput {

//The 'mask' as you say for the fields
private static final String IP_REGEX = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";

public TableVerifyInput() {
    final InputVerifier verifier = getInputVerifier();
    final DefaultCellEditor editor = getTableCellEditor(verifier);

    String[] cols = {"IP address", "Column 2"};
    Object[][] data = {{null, null}, {null, null}};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);

    JTable table = new JTable(model) {
        public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
            int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

            if (modelColumn == 0) {
                return editor;
            } else {
                return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        }
    };

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Cell Verify");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private InputVerifier getInputVerifier() {
    InputVerifier verifier = new InputVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
            String text = field.getText();
            return text.matches(IP_REGEX) || text.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
            boolean valid = verify(input);
            if (!valid) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid IP address");
            }
            return valid;
        }

    };
    return verifier;
}

private DefaultCellEditor getTableCellEditor(final InputVerifier verifier) {
    DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()) {
        {
            getComponent().setInputVerifier(verifier);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            if (!verifier.shouldYieldFocus(getComponent())) {
                return false;
            }
            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        @Override
        public JTextField getComponent() {
            return (JTextField) super.getComponent();
        }

    };
    return editor;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TableVerifyInput();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Once again, credit to SO User peeskillet for this contribution.

Comment: If I understood his code correctly, it verifies if the user entered the text in the specified regex format and then gives an error if it's wrong. But what I'm really looking for is an edit mask, because I don't want to bother the user with error messages.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by edit mask?  Where it only let's you type in certain characters or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes, specific characters in a specific format. Examples: HH:MM (for times), mm/dd/yyyy (for dates). In another words, I want a JFormattedTextField as the editor of each cell. It has to be impossible for the user to type any wrong character in any wrong format inside the cell.

Comment: I would 'guess' the way to do this would be to obtain the textField you select in the table, then use a key listener/adapter to monitor input into the field, only allowing what you need.

Comment: Yes, it might be a solution, but I'm trying to avoid programming all the input logic already present in the JFormattedTextField. I think Swing probably has way to override the default text container, but it's being hard to find it.

Comment: @user3685608 No problem.  If you found something that answers your question, then as you currently have no correct answers you may want to post your solution as an answer, should anyone else come across your question with a similar problem :)